# Trouble with autofs

Tags: ubuntu-mate, autofs

I need help with autofs. It is a little complicated.

I am stuck at this point. I have no /data directory.

```
The/data directory and the subdirectories fs1/, fs2/, and fs3/ should be automatically created, as you can see in the screenshot below.
$ ls /data
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg79a.jpg

https://linuxhint.com/mount-filesystems-automatically-on-demand-using-autofs/

This is my auto.sda2

```
/dev/sda2   ext3    UUID=5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75
```

My auto.master

```
#
# Sample auto.master file
# This is a 'master' automounter map and it has the following format:
# mount-point [map-type[,format]:]map [options]
# For details of the format look at auto.master(5).
#
#/misc  /etc/auto.misc
#
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
#   "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
#   options are explicitly given.
#
#/net   -hosts
#
# Include /etc/auto.master.d/*.autofs
# The included files must conform to the format of this file.
#
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
#
# Include central master map if it can be found using
# nsswitch sources.
#
# Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as
# above) in the included master map any keys that are the
# same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
# precedence.
#
+auto.master
/etc/auto.sda2
```

Comment: systemd can do that. This is a good [comparison](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570958/mount-vs-automount-systemd-units-which-one-to-use-for-what) between the two...

Comment: I am talking about autofs not automount. @kanehekili

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Why is drive formatted as ext3 and not the more common ext4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `automount` is the daemon part of `autofs`, but `systemd` uses the name automount in his context, too (see `man systemd.automount`).

Second, I assume you use an Ubuntu version still under support (e.g. 20.04, 22.04, ...).

As far as I understood you want to automount `/dev/sda2` as `/data/fs2`.

You need to have the package `autofs` installed (`sudo apt-get install autofs`). With it there are some example files in `/etc` where you can see how it works.

In your case there are multiple files involved.

1. `/etc/auto.master` (see `man auto.master` for complete syntax and options)
   There you already added the line `/etc/auto.sda2` which is not correct. The mountpoint is missing as you can see from the examples in the file. Correct is `/data /etc/auto.sda2`, but I would rather name it `auto.data`. But let's stick with `auto.sda2`
2. `/etc/auto.sda2`
   There this line needs to be inside (see `man 5 autofs` for complete syntax and options):

```
fs2 -fstype=ext3 :/dev/sda2
```

3. You have to create the root directories of the mountpoint: `sudo mkdir /data`
4. restart autofs: `sudo systemctl restart autofs`
5. at this point all is ready and you should be able to do `ls /data/fs2`

As the name "automount" says, it is mounted only on "demand", means when accessed. Usually `ls /data` would show an empty directory.

In the file `/etc/autofs.conf` (see `man 5 autofs.conf` for complete syntax and options) you can change several options. One is named `browse_mode` which is set to `no` by default. Search in the existing `/etc/autofs.conf` file for it, uncomment it and set it to `yes` (`browse_mode = yes`). Restart autofs (see above). Now you will always see the directories in `/data`, even if they are not yet mounted.

Comment: Where do I make this/ sudo mkdir /data ? @Marco